# How to capture a frame from PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint slide with three bullet points appearing as user presses Enter on keyboard. I want to save each of those presentation frames as separate images. SO, first image should contain only first bullet point, second should contain first two and third should contain all three.

If I just do standard export, all three bullet points appear in one image. I tried this, but it crashes:

```
 Image my_image = (Image)presentation.Slides[4].TimeLine.MainSequence[2];

 my_image.Save(@"..\img_test.jpg");
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: What does, "it crashes" mean?

Comment: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Drawing.Image'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

One (ugly) Way of doing this, would be to get the Text e.g.:

```
objTextRng = objSlide.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange;
```

and afterwards manypulating it the way you need it befor saving the slide.